# How to make a file filter by hooking kernel32.dll

Tags: python, file, winapi, hook, hide

I am a newbie to hooking. I am searching for a python program that can hide files or block it by filtering the results by filtering some of them using `win API hooking` . I have read that there is also another way to do it, using file system filtering driver, or using kernel mode API hooking, of which I got the idea from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32744/Driver-to-Hide-Processes-and-Files).

Anyway, I am python guy, so I want it to be in python, searching for which I got up to [PyBox](http://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/content/pybox-python-sandbox). This is where I can inject certain DLL into a application and then can run it.

Here is the code which do it:

```
 if kernel32.CreateProcessA(self.exe,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   creation_flags,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   byref(startupinfo),
                                   byref(process_information)):
            self.pid = process_information.dwProcessId
            self.tid = process_information.dwThreadId
            self.h_process = process_information.hProcess
            self.h_thread = process_information.hThread
            print "Process successfully launched with PID %d." % self.pid
            return True
        else:
            print "Process could not be launched!"
            raise WinError()
            return False
```

This creates process in suspended mode and then:

```
def resume(self):
        if (kernel32.ResumeThread(self.h_thread) == 0):
            print "Process could note be resumed!"
            raise WinError()
            return False
        else:
            print "Process resumed."
            return True
```

This function resumes the process after injecting the DLL. I am wondering two things:

1. Why not If I can block the process rather than resuming it. This will block the application from running. But which function of kernel32 should I call?
2. How can I implement `ntQueryDirectoryfile function` or `zwQueryDirectoryfile function` here so that I can add a filter to the file rather than blocking it. Do the DLL will then have any effect on the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the way.
I now guess at this point that kernel32.dll needs **kernel mode hooking** which is far out of reach from python.

`WINDDK` and `VS(Visual Studio)` provides the kernel debugger and environment to create .sys files which can be called into exe.

Just use function as per defined in `WIN32HLP`

Now I am just wondering if that exe could be made out of python( Which I prefer by the way)/